# Hide and Show embedded object in Word

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I want to create a word add-in where I can select an embedded file in a Word document and on clicking say a 'Hide' button in my add in it should hide the file and replace it with say **hidden** text. Also, I want to reveal the file by clicking the 'Show' button on my add-in.
Can someone please advise how to achieve it?Note I when file is hidden its contents should also be hidden (encrypted).

I tried few approaches(like copying the content of the selected file on the clipboard and converting it to stream. Encrypt the stream and save it as a bookmark) but somehow I am not able to retrieve the name from memory stream of the clipboard and unable to get the desired behavior.

Comment: What exactly is the hidden file that is embedded within the word document?

Comment: Hi Rich, the file can be any type..like image,text,pdf etc

Comment: @VikrantYadav By the way, if you find information here helpful, show your appreciation by upvoting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the embedded content in a [custom XML part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/custom-xml-parts-overview), and replace it with a field or hyperlink that contains some sort of custom ID, to refer to later. You could also [make the field or hyperlink hidden text](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2030049&seqNum=16). But the type of the content matters; some things in a document are difficult to get out of the document.

Comment: Hi Chris, I am trying to hide the hidden file as well as its contents.I am not sure how to hide the embedded file as well as the contents.

Comment: @VikrantYadav Hiding something on the surface of a document is one thing - Encrpyting / hiding the *content* is another matter entirely. There's no provision in Word for something like that. I think the approach Chris suggests is your only chance. You need to research the pointers he gives. Realizing this will *not* be trivial and will involve working with the underlying Word Open XML, as well, to manage the Relationships that link embedded content into the document. You need to research Word Open XML as well as CustomXMLParts quite thoroughly.

Comment: It would necessarily be stored as an encoded string since it has to go into XML, so in that sense it would be unclear as to what is in the docx file. But afaik that's the best you could do.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Word, Hidden is a font attribute and objects can be hidden from print by changing the Hidden attribute setting on the Paragraph Font where the object is inserted or anchored. The objects will still appear on the screen when editing, but again, they will not print and when the document is converted to PDF, they will not display.

Depending on exactly how your document(s) are setup, you might investigate using a Custom Style, which contain the Font Hidden attribute, and then apply or remove it as required.

Comment: Hidden content can be displayed while editing, but that won't necessarily be the case. It's a user option under File > Options > Display. and FYI @VikrantYadav It can be toggled in code but the user cannot be prevented from changing it.